# Error on CSV to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Not sure why this isn't working, it's adapted from code that does work. Looks like I need an explicit cast but I'm not sure why or where to put it. The error is:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary{string,string}}' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary{string,string}'"

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> Data_Entry(string dataEntity, string dataCategory, string dataStream = "")
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.csv");
        var header = lines.First().Split(',');
        return (from line in lines.Skip(1)
            let cols = line.Split(',')
            where cols[0].ToUpper() == dataEntity & cols[1].ToUpper() == dataCategory & cols[4].ToUpper() == dataStream
            select header.Select((h, i) => new { header = h, index = i })
            .ToDictionary(o => o.header, o => cols[o.index])
        );
    }
```

Comment: It might help if you explained what this code is trying to do, exactly. There are a couple of answers below that correctly point out that your declared return type and your `return` statement are in conflict, but it's hard to go beyond that without knowing your objective.

Comment: I want to pull a single matching row from the structured CSV (only one match is possible) via the where clause, as well as the header row, with the header values as keys and the row values as values in the returned Dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Linq query is returning an `IEnumerable<T>` object where T is of type Dictionary instead of what you are expecting as a Dictionary.

If I understand your code you essentially want to create a list of dictionaries where the column header is the key and the line's column index value is the value. Since dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, you can't turn the entire thing into one dictionary object as there will be exceptions from the duplicate keys.

So essentially you want to pull the ToDictionary() call out of the Linq statement and apply it to the result of the Linq statement instead to get your dictionary. Unfortunately, this will result in said duplicate key errors with the way it's currently coded so instead of returning a dictionary you might consider a different datastructure or change the return type to be an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>>` type.

Edit:
Based on the follow-up information in the comments the following will get you where you need to be. Notice that I added the FirstOrDefault() call to the results of the Linq query. This means that it will return the first result (which is type `Dictionary<string,string>`) which satisfies the method's return type. It's worth having a check in the calling code for a null return just in case even if you're confident it will never be null.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> Data_Entry(string dataEntity, string dataCategory, string dataStream = "")
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.csv");
    var header = lines.First().Split(',');
    return (from line in lines.Skip(1)
        let cols = line.Split(',')
        where cols[0].ToUpper() == dataEntity & cols[1].ToUpper() == dataCategory & cols[4].ToUpper() == dataStream
        select header.Select((h, i) => new { header = h, index = i })
        .ToDictionary(o => o.header, o => cols[o.index])
    ).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: The code this was adapted from did pull a List<Dictionary<string, string>>. In this case what I want to do is pull a single row from the structured CSV file; the where clause will ensure a unique key is pulled as only a single row will match.

Comment: In that case move the ToDictionary outside of the Linq statement as right now it's being applied inside and therefore the query is returning an IEnumerable of dictionaries.

Comment: That sounds right but I'm not sure how to accomplish it. If I pull the statement as-is out, the variables inside the Linq statement are out of scope.

Comment: Another option would be to add .FirstOrDefault() to the results of the Linq query. This would select the first one or a null object (in this case). You need to be sure you are only ever going to get one or no result from the Linq query and handle the case that the return is null.

Comment: The CSV is structured, the where clause and arguments can only return a single matched row for this code and file.

Comment: Edited my answer above with the solution you are looking for based on the comments. If you still have questions let me know.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! So because the Linq structure couldn't ensure the return of a single Dictionary object, it was returning IEnumerable<T>, a collection of Dictionary objects (though in this case only one). I expect there is a better way to do what I want than the Linq statement I used, but your answer works with my initial code.

Comment: Linq **always** returns an IEnumerable and doesn't try to second-guess if you just want one object or all. You need to explicitly specify which item (or items) in the collection you want.